# How to Link to a Website or Safari within my iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, mobile-safari

I am using Xcode to develop an iOS app and I need to know how to link a website to a button to open with in the app. I want o have a drop down bar that has buttons to return to a separate screen and a button to save the link  to another place. Is there a way to open a website or a link to safari with my app?

Answer (score 4):

You can open a website directly by using a UIWebView object in your app.

You can get Safari to open a web site by invoking something like `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myURL]`.

Comment: first declare your url:
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com"];